# The url of the images if I use a subdomain

Tags: php, html

I have a problem that is related to the URL of the images if I use a subdomain.
For example, if the image is located at address

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/photo.jpg
```

And if I want to use subdomain to speed up page load, in this case subdomain is:

```
http://img.mydomain.com
```

How should look like the url to the image foto.jpg if I use subdomain?

The path for subdomain:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/img/
```

The path for images folder:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/images/
```

Comment: How exactly would it speed up page loads? Is the subdomain hosted on a different server?

Comment: @anirudh4444 Web browsers can be limited to 2 or 3 simultaneous web requests per host to play nice with web servers. By hosting your assets on multiple subdomains you're basically inviting the browser to hammer your server in one hit, making it load faster.

Comment: It speeds up page load times, because web browsers only allow X connections per domain. So, if you put your images on a subdomain, you can achieve 2X connections, thus a speedier experience per browser.

Answer (score 8):

just add an alias to your `img` subdomain and keep the same structure. This way if you need to change in the future it will be transparent

### edit:

is also good to have more than one subdomain for assets. like `img01` `img02` and so on. But be these subdomains consistent.

like if you have the image `image1.jpg` that targets to

`http://img01.domain.com/images/image1.jpg`

the next time the imagen appears in the code should appear as

`http://img01.domain.com/images/image1.jpg`

AND NOT as

`http://img02.domain.com/images/image1.jpg`

**so the cache can optimize the calls**.

I usually use this formula

```
  return sprintf("http://img%02s.domain.com", abs(crc32($imagename) % (9)));
```

this way the subdomain will be always consistent with the image name

### edit 2:

Browsers [limit the amount of connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser/985704#985704) opens peer server. So by having multiple subdomains you are `faking` this and therefore improving the load speed of the page.

But in the other hand if for a same image you load it from `more` than one different server the browser's cache can't operate because it doesn't know that you want to load the same image.

So by hashing the image name you are obtaining **always** the same server and then obtaining the best of both worlds: more connections opens **AND** browser caching

Comment: don't say that. Every day is a nice day to learn something new. Check my edits. Saludos

Comment: it doesnt work for me. subdomains should have different ip adresses?

Comment: @PiKey not required. you can have simple CNAMES targeting to the same `backend` host. This is only an `illusion` for the browser. but if you are using apache remember adding `ServerAlias` for each hostname to apache reply to the requests

Answer (score 3):

If your subdomain's document root is:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/img/
```

And your images at are:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/images/
```

Then you will not be able to access them. You'd have to navigate to `http://img.mydomain.com/../images/photo.jpg` which, for very obvious security reasons, is not possible.

Your subdomain's document root should instead be:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/images/
```

And then your URL is:

```
http://img.mydomain.com/photo.jpg
```

Comment: But if I create subdomain using Cpanel it will create new folder with the same name as subdomain. How can I create subdomain for existing folder?

Comment: @Sergio: So you're changing this to a Server Administration question now?

Comment: I'm not changing anything, the question remains the same. Just asking how can I do that.

Comment: If you can't change the server configuration, the only option is to copy the images to the other folder or us an alias as Gabriel said. There is no other way.

Comment: URL Rewrite? But I guess it will not be that efficient for images or other static resources...